# ggplot Complex GridExtra Layout

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to layout three plots in the following fashion:

```
[FirstPlot]
[2nd] [3rd]
```

The first plot is on top of the second and third plots. And the first plot is double the width of the second and third plots. Let's now generate the dummy data:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)

plot1 <- qplot(1, 1)
plot2 <- qplot(1, 1)
plot3 <- qplot(1, 1)

lay <- rbind(c(1,1),
             c(2,3))
```

And the syntax to plot this out should be:

```
grid.arrange(grobs = c(plot1, plot2, plot3), 
             layout_matrix = lay)
```

Actually it should not be that because it does not work. And I get the following error. What should the command be to plot this all out? I think I got the `grobs` part wrong.

> Error in t:b : NA/NaN argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*grobs* argument needs *list()* not *c()* :

```
grid.arrange(grobs = list(plot1, plot2, plot3), 
             layout_matrix = lay)
```

---

```
?grid.arrange
```

> **grobs** list of grobs

Comment: Bonus `top = "Top Label"` gives you a top title

Answer (score 4):

I want to provide a [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) solution because it's such a cool package:

```
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) + geom_boxplot()
plot3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()

# One way of doing it
plot1 + (plot2 + plot3) + plot_layout(ncol = 1)

# Another, alternative solution
plot1 /
  (plot2 | plot3)
```

Which returns:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy fix. Use `grobs = list(plot1, plot2, plot3)`

Comment: I'm trying that but get this error `Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic` --EDIT-- I did a typo. Nevermind, it works! Thank you.